# "Flex: none" vs. Non-specified (omitted) flex property

Tags: html, css, flexbox

Is there a difference between `flex: none` and leaving the flex property undefined?

I tested it in several simple layouts and I don't see the difference.

For example, I could remove `flex: none` from blue item (see code below), and the layout, as I understand, remains the same. Does I understand it right?

And, the second question, what about more complex layouts? Should I write `flex: none` or I can simply omit it?

```css
.flex-container {
  display: flex;
  width: 400px;
  height: 150px;
  background-color: lightgrey;
}
.flex-item {
  margin: 10px;
}
.item1 {
  flex: none; /* Could be omitted? */
  background-color: cornflowerblue;
}
.item2 {
  flex: 1;
  background-color: orange;
}
.item3 {
  flex: 1;
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex-container">
  <div class="flex-item item1">flex item 1</div>
  <div class="flex-item item2">flex item 2</div>
  <div class="flex-item item3">flex item 3</div>
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/r4s8z835/

Answer (score 40, accepted):

> Is there a difference between `flex: none` and leaving the flex property undefined?

`flex: none` is equivalent to `flex: 0 0 auto`, which is shorthand for:

- `flex-grow: 0`
- `flex-shrink: 0`
- `flex-basis: auto`

Simply put, `flex: none` sizes the flex item according to the width / height of the content, but doesn't allow it to shrink. This means the item has the potential to overflow the container.

If you omit the `flex` property (and longhand properties), the initial values are as follows:

- `flex-grow: 0`
- `flex-shrink: 1`
- `flex-basis: auto`

This is known as `flex: initial`.

This means the item will not grow when there is free space available (just like `flex: none`), but it can shrink when necessary (unlike `flex: none`).

---

> I could remove `flex: none` from blue item (see code below), and the layout, as I understand, remains the same.

In terms of [**your demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/r4s8z835/), the reason there is no difference when `flex: none` is removed is that the two siblings (`.item2` and `.item3`) are flexible (`flex: 1`), and there is enough space in the container to accommodate the content of `.item1`.

However, if `.item1` had more content, `flex: none` would make a big difference.

[**revised fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/r4s8z835/4/)

```css
.flex-container {
  display: flex;
  width: 400px;
  height: 150px;
  background-color: lightgrey;
}
.flex-item {
  margin: 10px;
}
.item1 {
  flex: none; /* Now try removing it. */
  background-color: cornflowerblue;
}
.item2 {
  flex: 1;
  background-color: orange;
}
.item3 {
  flex: 1;
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex-container">
  <div class="flex-item item1">flex item 1 flex item 1 flex item 1 flex item 1flex item 1 flex item 1flex item 1flex item 1</div>
  <div class="flex-item item2">flex item 2</div>
  <div class="flex-item item3">flex item 3</div>  
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you very much for detailed explanation, it's an excellent answer. As I understand from it, if one of the siblings (the blue one) have fixed width (assuming it is an image or input field), it would not be the difference between omitted and `auto` for it?

Comment: Mistyped. I mean, the difference between omitted and `none`. Here is updated fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/r4s8z835/5/

Comment: There's also another factor to consider: http://stackoverflow.com/q/36247140/3597276

Comment: As referenced in the link in my previous comment, flex items cannot, by default, shrink below the size of their content. The initial setting on flex items is `min-width: auto`; You need to override this default with the `overflow` property or `min-width: 0` . https://jsfiddle.net/r4s8z835/6/

Answer (score 1):

According to https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/f/flex/#article-header-id-4 the difference between these is that flex:none will not shrink in an overflow situation. The default propery is flex: 0 1 auto, while flex: none changes it to flex: 0 0 auto.

```
<div class="flex-container">
  <div class="flex-item item1">flex item 1</div>
  <div class="flex-item item2">flex item 2</div>
  <div class="flex-item item3">flex item 3</div>  
</div>

<div class="flex-container">
  <div class="flex-item item1 item-1-flex-none">flex item 1</div>
  <div class="flex-item item2">flex item 2</div>
  <div class="flex-item item3">flex item 3</div>  
</div>
.flex-container {
  display: flex;
  width: 100px;
  height: 150px;
  overflow:scroll;
  background-color: lightgrey;
}

.flex-item {
  margin: 10px;
}

.item1 {
  background-color: cornflowerblue;
}

.item2 {
  flex: 1;
  background-color: orange;
}

.item3 {
  flex: 1;
  background-color: green;
}


.item-1-flex-none{flex:none;}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/r4s8z835/2/

for example if I reduce your container size and apply overflow:scroll this happens.